# R shiny - observeEvent - make the commands execute in order and in real time

Tags: r, shiny

My shiny app has to perform some slightly slower server-side calculations so I want the user to be able to keep track of what is happening while they are waiting. Here is a minimal example of the structure of my app:

https://gist.github.com/0bb9efb98b0a5e431a8f

```
runGist("0bb9efb98b0a5e431a8f")
```

What I would like to happen is:

1. Click submit
2. The app moves to the 'Output' tab panel
3. It displays the messages and outputs in the order they are listed in `observeEvent`

What actually happens is:

1. Click submit
2. Everything is executed server side at once
3. The UI is updated at the end

Is it possible to get what I want here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could not come up with a solution using your approach. `Shiny` seems to wait until everything in `server = function(input, output)` is computed, and displays the results just afterwards, when all components for `output$...` are available. I don't know if there is a way around that.

There is however a solution implemented, which you could try: [Progress indicators](http://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/progress.html)

Implementation using your code:

```r
library(shiny)

shinyApp(
  ui = navbarPage(title="test", id="mainNavbarPage",

                  tabPanel("Input", value="tabinput",
                           numericInput('n', 'Number of obs', 100),
                           actionButton(inputId="submit_button", label="Submit")
                  ),

                  tabPanel("Output", value="taboutput",
                           plotOutput('plot')
                  )
  ),
  server = function(input, output, session) {


    observeEvent(input$submit_button, {
      # Move to results page
      updateNavbarPage(session, "mainNavbarPage", selected="taboutput")

      withProgress(message = "Computing results", detail = "fetching data", value = 0, {

        Sys.sleep(3)

        incProgress(0.25, detail = "computing results")

        # Perform lots of calculations that may take some time
        Sys.sleep(4)

        incProgress(0.25, detail = "part two")

        Sys.sleep(2)
        incProgress(0.25, detail = "generating plot")

        Sys.sleep(2)
      })

      output$plot <- renderPlot({hist(runif(input$n)) })

    })
})
```